# NSMutableArray accessing NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I read in 4 fields from a database and store them in NSMutableDictionary. Each record gets stored in a NSMutableArray. So far so good.

I have function (dont have the source) that requires a NSArray (Description field) be sent to it. I was trying to find a way to send the 2nd field from the dictionary as though it was one NSArray. The other way is I could create a new NSArray and have it duplicated for this function which seems like a waste.

Here is the code I use to read the DB:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,  sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    nf_myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        Descr = [ GetText:"Description" cs:compiledStatement];

        ID = [ GetText:"_id" cs:compiledStatement];
        Wt = [ GetText:"Weight" cs:compiledStatement];
        deflt = [ GetText:"deflt" cs:compiledStatement];

        NSMutableDictionary *nf_myRow = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


        [nf_myRow setObject:Descr forKey:@"Description"];
        [nf_myRow setObject:ID forKey:@"ID"];
        [nf_myRow setObject:Wt forKey:@"Weight"];
        [nf_myRow setObject:deflt forKey:@"deflt"];

        [nf_myData addObject:nf_myRow];
```

Comment: You have no choice. Create a 2nd array with just the values you want.

Comment: What does "the second field from the dictionary" mean? Do you mean you want to extract whatever the "ID" is?

Comment: the ID or whatever "field" is needed, basically being able to pass the NSarray for just that one object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use key-value coding:

```
 NSArray* arr = [nf_myData valueForKey: @"ID"];
```

(or whatever the heck you think you mean by "the second field").

Comment: Here's my discussion of key-value coding: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_key_value_coding_2

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could access the dictionary and basically send it like a pointer in C.  I just sent the [nf_myData valueForKey: @"ID"] directly to the function and it worked great. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "like a pointer in C". Objective C _is_ C. An Objective-C object reference _is_ a pointer in C. Your dictionary `nf_myRow` _is_ a pointer in C. All the objects it "contains" are pointers in C. An array, a dictionary: they are just collections of pointers. They are very inexpensive, lightweight things. This is why your original question was so strange. "A new NSArray" containing the same objects as the dictionary is not "a waste"; it is hardly any overhead at all.

Comment: Thus for example when you say `NSArray* arr2 = [NSArray arrayWithArray: arr]` there are not really two arrays at all. Well, there are. But they are just collections of pointers to the very same objects. So once you have `arr1`, even if it "contains" thousands of objects, `arr2` adds only a tiny bit more memory usage (thousands of itsy-bitsy pointers).